# Custom VirtueMart Options

Tags: php, api, joomla, virtuemart

I'm working on a project that ties into an API and uses virtuemart. Basically a user can buy time for a phone card. the few things I need help with are:

A) can/how can I create a custom php function once the user signs up. For instance, the user adds Items to the cart and proceeds to checkout. once the user clicks checkout they need to create an account, after they create an account is there an area in this process that allows for a custom function so that I can tie the creation of the account to an API?

B) same as above but after checkout. After the checkout goes through, how can I make it so the new values are sent to the API? Is there an area in the files that allow for custom functions here.

C) Lastly is it possible to add more options the the virtuemart customer account maintnance screen. I want an option that will tie into the API and show them exactly how much time the have left for their phone card. This information will be provided by the api.

Answer (score 0):

All of these things can be achieved with a System Plugin. You would simply look for the right url, get any information from the result screen with regex, call your API and insert any changes back into the screen.

I'm not specifically aware of any VM functions for this, but as VM is in flux with Version 2 getting closer, it may not be a good time for any such investment in any case.